# How to change color based on number

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have just started to learn coding and I have got a problem now.
I have made this black circle witch has number inside and it goes higher every time you click it but I would want now that even numbers would be blue and odd numbers red (1=red, 2=blue, 3=red etc.)

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var laskuri = document.getElementById('laskuri'); 
    function kasvata() {
        var i =++
        laskuri.innerHTML + i;

        asetaTaustaVari();
    }

    function asetaTaustaVari() {

    }

    laskuri.onclick = kasvata;

}
```

```css
* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    main {
        text-align: center;
    }

    #laskuri {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        margin: 50px auto;
        font-size: 200px;
        padding: 30px 0px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<div id=laskuri>0</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do it by putting an `if` condition and setting `color` in it

```
 if (val % 2 == 0) {
      color = "blue";
    } else {
      color = "red";
    }
```

or use ternary operator like this

```js
function kasvata() {
  var color = '';
  var i = ++
  document.getElementById('laskuri').innerHTML + i;
  var el = document.getElementById('laskuri');
  color = el.innerHTML % 2 == 0 ? "blue" : "red";
  el.style.color = color;
  asetaTaustaVari();
}

function asetaTaustaVari() {

}

laskuri.onclick = kasvata;
```

```html
<html lang="fi">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Laskuri</title>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    main {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #laskuri {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      margin: 50px auto;
      font-size: 200px;
      padding: 30px 0px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <div id=laskuri>0</div>

  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by few ways:

1. Preferred: You can use a special class-name and use it with your element. In JS code you'll just change a class-name depends on the counter:

   ```
   <style>
       .color_red {
           color: red;
       }
       .color_blue{
           color: red;
       }
   </style>

   <script>
   window.onload = function(){
       var laskuri = document.getElementById('laskuri');
       var i = 0;
       function kasvata() {
           i++;
           laskuri.innerHTML = i;

           asetaTaustaVari();
       }

       function asetaTaustaVari() {
           var clName = i % 2 === 0 ? 'color_blue' : 'color_red';
           laskuri.className = clName;
       }

       laskuri.onclick = kasvata;

   }
   </script>
   ```
2. Optional: You can change colors of an element with styles changing. The code is almost the same:

   ```
   function asetaTaustaVari() {
       var color = i % 2 === 0 ? 'blue' : 'red';
       laskuri.styles.color = color;
   }
   ```

P.S.: In your code, please, don't write in your own native language (Finnish / Sweden), please, use english words ALWAYS. Not Laskuri - but Counter.

Comment: Okay Im sorry about language I will code in english now on but thank you for answer!

Answer (score 1):

You could get the number from the html and use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). Then increment the number and add it to the html.

Then using the [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) you can change the  color.

For example:

```js
function kasvata() {
  var elm = document.getElementById('laskuri');
  if (elm && elm.innerHTML !== "") {
    var number = parseInt(elm.innerHTML, 10);
    number = number + 1;
    elm.innerHTML = elm.innerHTML = number.toString();
    asetaTaustaVari(number, elm);
  }
}

function asetaTaustaVari(i, elm) {
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    elm.style.color = "blue";
  } else {
    elm.style.color = "red";
  }
}

laskuri.onclick = kasvata;
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  text-align: center;
}

#laskuri {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 50px auto;
  font-size: 200px;
  padding: 30px 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id=laskuri>0</div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
<!-- Javascript -->

function kasvata() {
            var i =++
                document.getElementById('laskuri').innerHTML + i;

            asetaTaustaVari();
        }

        function asetaTaustaVari() {
            var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
            var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
            var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
            var thergb = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
            console.log(thergb);
            document.getElementById("laskuri").style.color = thergb;
        }

        laskuri.onclick = kasvata;
```

```css
<!-- CSS3 -->

* {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        main {
            text-align: center;
        }

        #laskuri {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            margin: 50px auto;
            font-size: 200px;
            padding: 30px 0px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<!-- HTML5 -->

<html lang="fi">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Laskuri</title>
</head>
<body>
<main>
    <div id=laskuri>0</div>
<main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of any other function. I think it is required only a ternary operator. You have done almost all thing just modify your javascript code like bellow

```
<script>
function kasvata() {
    var i =++
    document.getElementById('laskuri').innerHTML + i;
    var val = document.getElementById('laskuri').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('laskuri').style.color = val % 2 == 0 ? "blue" : "red";
}
laskuri.onclick = kasvata;
</script>
```

I hope you can change the minimum to get it done. Here is the example https://jsfiddle.net/doehxkLy/

And if you want to change the color randomly. Please change the line

```
document.getElementById('laskuri').style.color = val % 2 == 0 ? "blue" : "red";
```

To

```
document.getElementById('laskuri').style.color = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);
```

Thumbs up.

Answer (score -1):

made you a small codepen for it:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jZrELZ

you just need a `if` to see if innerHTML of laskuri is even or odd. I resolve the rest with adding/removing a class. you could also change the background directly with javascript.